# error using String class to convert a double to a string

Tags: string, code-review, compilation-errors

i wanted to convert a double to a string i tested several examples online i allawys get the same error.

the code :

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop()
{
  double val =3.2222;
  String stringOne =  String(val, 3);
  Serial.print(stringOne);
}
```

the errors :

```
sketch_jun02c.ino: In function ‘void loop()’:
sketch_jun02c.ino:10:36: error: call of overloaded ‘String(double&, int)’ is ambiguous
sketch_jun02c.ino:10:36: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:192:0,
                 from sketch_jun02c.ino:2:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:70:11: note: String::String(long unsigned int, unsigned char)
  explicit String(unsigned long, unsigned char base=10);
           ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:69:11: note: String::String(long int, unsigned char)
  explicit String(long, unsigned char base=10);
           ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:68:11: note: String::String(unsigned int, unsigned char)
  explicit String(unsigned int, unsigned char base=10);
           ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:67:11: note: String::String(int, unsigned char)
  explicit String(int, unsigned char base=10);
           ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:66:11: note: String::String(unsigned char, unsigned char)
  explicit String(unsigned char, unsigned char base=10);
           ^
```

Comment: Which IDE version are you using? The fact it's showing `/usr/share/arduino` tells me you installed it with apt-get (or similar), so you're probably on something ridiculously ancient.

Comment: Yes i used apt-get, the version i am using is: ARDUINO 1.0.5 - 2013.05.15, is there a way to update it without deleting the old version ?

Comment: Download the new version from the website, extract it, and run it.

Comment: Yea I have done that already thanks Majenko ;)

Comment: The current Arduino SDK version is 1.8.2.  So 1.0.5 is really old.  Package managers do not necessarily stay up to date.  Especially with packages that don't make up the core of the OS.  In C++ the types of the arguments are just as important as the name of the function you are calling.  No (perfect) match means no function will be called.  So it does not look like there is a matching "Strings()" function.  That is, a "Strings()" function where the type of the argument is a double.

Comment: Yea thank you, after upgradign the IDE to 1.8.2 the program worked fine !

Comment: Post your own solution as an answer and accept it to close this question

Comment: @LookAlterno Thank you for telling me it is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed arduino using apt-get and I didnt notice that I had an old version. I upgraded my arduino and it worked fine.